# How to change opacity for hyper terminal?

Tags: command-line, 20.04

Found article regarding changing **opacity** of **hyper** terminal for `Mac Os` and `Windows`but not for `Ubuntu`.

How to change **opacity** for **hyper** terminal on **Ubuntu**?

Comment: What is "hyper terminal on Ubuntu"?

Comment: @Pilot6 [hyper](https://hyper.is/)

Answer (score 4):

It appears the [`hyper-opacity`](https://github.com/lucleray/hyper-opacity) plugin only works on Windows and MacOS.

This seems to be an upstream issue: The hyper terminal is based on Electron, and `hyper-opacity` uses the Electron function [BrowserWindow.setOpacity()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winsetopacityopacity-windows-macos). This function, according to the Electron docs, "does nothing" on Linux. According to [this issue thread](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/381), this seems to be because Chrome / Chromium (which in turn is the basis for Electron) doesn't support changing the opacity on Linux.

In any case, it seems this is in the hands of the Electron developers to solve.

Comment: This seems to be an upstream issue: hyper terminal is based on Electron, and `hyper-opacity` uses the Electron function [BrowserWindow.setOpacity()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winsetopacityopacity-windows-macos). This function, according to the Electron docs, "does nothing" on Linux. And if I got the gist of [this issue thread](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/381) correctly, this is because Chrome / Chromium (which in turn is the basis for Electron) doesn't support changing the opacity on Linux.

Comment: Can I add that to my answer? Or you can edit if you like.

Comment: Sure, feel free to add the info to your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is still of concern, but I just found another hyper plugin for transparency/opacity that works on Linux (Ubuntu 22.04 at least).

You can try hyper-transparent (check their site for install/set-up config):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyper-transparent

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice to know! 

Comment: This is probably for another thread, but as OP was posting about opacity/transparency not working on Linux (found the the plugin just above for it), I can't find a way to incorporate vibrancy on hyper terminal in Linux. I feel like it is something people usually want to combine together (opacity + vibrancy). If anyone knows of a workaround!